# How to use @Cacheable with method return type Stream<Object> in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I have following JPA method that fetches stream of objects

```
@Cacheable("accounts")
    Stream<Account> findAccounts(int branchCode, int accountCode);
```

Since the stream will close after calling the method therefore I am getting following error when I call the method for second time.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

What I like to do is; cache the content of stream i.e. accounts and read from cache for all subsequent calls. 
What would be the best way to achieve this ?

**UPDATE**: Note that I am aware of using a List but it is required to keep return type Stream.

Comment: cache the `List<Account>` instead of a `Stream` may be?

Comment: that works but I don't want to break  the API contract. I.e. return a list instead of streaming

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you (or why it didn't). If it did, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 7):

You cannot cache a `Stream`. What you can cache, though, is any kind of `Collection` (preferably `List`).

In order not to break the API contract, you simply extract a private method that returns a `List`, and annotate it with `@Cacheable`. Then, the original method (without the `@Cacheable` annotation) just calls the cacheable method and calls `stream()` on it, constructing a new `Stream` from the `List` every time it's called, like that:

```
Stream<Account> findAccounts(int branchCode, int accountCode) {
    return findAccountList(branchCode, accountCode).stream();
}

@Cacheable("accounts")
private List<Account> findAccountList(int branchCode, int accountCode);
```

---

However, if you were **extremely** determined to cache a lazily-evaluating data structure (which I do **not** recommend), you could use [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL)'s [`SeqBuffer`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/blob/master/jOOL/src/main/java/org/jooq/lambda/SeqBuffer.java) (it's package-private, though, so I guess you'd just need to copy the code).

*Disclaimer*: I am the author of the [`SeqBuffer`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/blob/master/jOOL/src/main/java/org/jooq/lambda/SeqBuffer.java) class.